# Set a Predefined Range of a Counter in Redis

Tags: redis, range, counter

How do I predefine a range of a Counter in Redis while setting it up. I want the Counter to have a predefined MAX and a MIN value(specifically in my case MIN value is 0) such that INCR or DECR return an error if the value is surpassing this Range. I went through the Redis Documentation and i didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis does not provide this built-in, but you can use it to build it yourself. There are many ways to do this, my personal preference is using Lua scripts - read [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) for more background.

In this case, I'd use this script:

```
local val = tonumber(redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]))
if not val then
    val = 0
end

local inc = val + tonumber(ARGV[1])
if inc < tonumber(ARGV[2]) or inc > tonumber(ARGV[3]) then
    error('Counter is out of bounds')
else
    return redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], inc)
end
```

Here's the output of a sample run from the command line:

```
$ redis-cli --eval incrbyminmax.lua foo , 5 0 10
(integer) 5
$ redis-cli --eval incrbyminmax.lua foo , 5 0 10
(integer) 10
$ redis-cli --eval incrbyminmax.lua foo , 5 0 10
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_ada0f9d33a6278f3e55797b9b4c89d5d8a012601): @user_script:8: user_script:8: Counter is out of bounds 
$ redis-cli --eval incrbyminmax.lua foo , -9 0 10
(integer) 1
$ redis-cli --eval incrbyminmax.lua foo , -9 0 10
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_ada0f9d33a6278f3e55797b9b4c89d5d8a012601): @user_script:8: user_script:8: Counter is out of bounds
```

Comment: Great answer!! 1 more doubt though: Will Lua Script be thread safe? Lets assume I have Server 1 and Server 2 calling the script to decrease Counter from 1 to 0. I am hoping Redis being Single threaded, only one of the call will return 0 and the other will return error. Can you validate my understanding?

Comment: Thanks & validated - scripts are atomic and blocking.

Comment: Yes, I wrote some scripts too. Works great. I am not using this counter from anywhere else in my code, so shouldn't have other concurrency issues as well. I have marked your answer as correct. it will display once I have enough reputation.

Comment: @ItamarHaber How could this possibly be atomic? You do a GET. Perform some math locally, and then perform a SET. It is totally possible to call increment twice, and only have the value incremented once with this solution.

Comment: @Cruncher this is a server-side script - it is atomic as the server is blocked while it is running